# setString(0,string) not setting the string in java

Tags: java, hibernate, hql

Below is my code inside a method named getUrlDetails() of WebsiteAvailability class

inside the method:  getUrlDetails(String selUrl)

```
List<WebsiteAvailability>avaList=new ArrayList<WebsiteAvailability>

String selquery="select w.statusCode,w.updateTime,s.statusCodeValue from WebsiteAvailability     w,StatusCodes s where w.statusCode=s.statusCodeNo and w.url=?";
avaList=session.createQuery(selquery).setString(0,selUrl).list();
```

Here this is hibernate java application.And StatusCode and WebsiteAvailability are POJO classes(generated by hibernate).So in HQL query I am using entity classes instead of database table names.I am using postgresql.
My problem is I am not getting the list of items which match where condition.In place of ?(placeholder) it is not taking supplied input.It is taking ? itself
Can someone please help me..

Answer (score 0):

<strike>Use **setString(1, ...)**</strike>
EDIT: No, it is setString(0, ...)

You can try using a named parameter:

```
String selquery="select w.statusCode,w.updateTime,s.statusCodeValue from WebsiteAvailability     w,StatusCodes s where w.statusCode=s.statusCodeNo and w.url=:selUrl";
avaList=session.createQuery(selquery).setString("selUrl",selUrl).list();
```

Comment: It is giving could not resolve property statusCode.Why am I getting this?

Comment: Try using fully qulified name: "... from " + WebsiteAvailability.class.getName() + "...".

Comment: How to give fully qualified name.And here between websiteavailability and statuscodes table have foriegn key relationship